How to log out user from Auth0 if token refresh fails in Next.js using Axios interceptor?
I'm using the Auth0 SDK in my Next.js application to manage authentication, and I've set up an Axios interceptor to handle refreshing the access token automatically when it expires. Here's the basic setup I have for the Axios interceptor:
async function refreshAccessToken() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN_API);
    const { access_token } = data;
    return {
      access_token,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

export function setupResponseInterceptor(axiosInstance: AxiosInstance) {
  axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    async error => {
      const originalRequest = error.config;
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error) && error.response?.status === 401) {
        if (!isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken) {
          isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = true;
          try {
            refreshAccessToken().then(res => {
              
            });
          } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
          }
        }
        const retryOriginalRequest = new Promise(resolve => {
          addSubscriber((accessToken: any) => {
            originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
            resolve(axios(originalRequest));
          });
        });
        return retryOriginalRequest;
      }

      throw error;
    },
  );
}


What I Tried:
I set up an Axios interceptor in my Next.js application to automatically refresh the Auth0 access token when a 401 error occurs. In the interceptor, I attempted to refresh the token using a custom function (refreshAuthToken()). The token refresh generally works, but I'm unsure how to handle scenarios where the token refresh fails. Specifically, I haven't been able to successfully log out the user from Auth0 when the refresh attempt fails.
What I Expected:
I was expecting to find a way to log out the user from Auth0 within the Axios interceptor if the token refresh fails. Ideally, I want the user to be redirected to a specific URL (e.g., the home page) after being logged out. I need guidance on how to properly invoke the Auth0 logout function in this context and any best practices for handling such failures gracefully.

Please check @auth0/nextjs-auth0 docs in case you use it. They have function that refreshes token for you.
https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/types/session_get_access_token.GetAccessToken.html
// app/my-api/route.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getAccessToken } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export async function GET() {
  const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken();
  return NextResponse.json({ foo: 'bar' });
}

// Or, it's slightly more efficient to use the `req`, `res` args if you're
// using another part of the SDK like `withApiAuthRequired` or `getSession`.
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getAccessToken, withApiAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

const GET = withApiAuthRequired(async function GET(req) {
  const res = new NextResponse();
  const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken(req, res);
  return NextResponse.json({ foo: 'bar' }, res);
});

export { GET };

or like this
// app/my-page/page.js
import { getAccessToken } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default async function MyPage({ params, searchParams }) {
  const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken();
  return <h1>My Page</h1>;
}

It depends how you use it. Provide me more code and I will be able to support you how to configure refresh token in axios interceptor.

I have implemented the access token refresh logic, but I need to ensure that the user is automatically logged out if the refresh token expires or if the access token refresh process fails.

You use auth0 and give them this responsiibility. So when regreshToken is expired the user in their state will be empty. No worries. I suggest you to deep dive into @auth0/nextjs-auth0 and auth0 docs for get better understanding how this thing works. Provide more code and we will figure out.

check examples https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/main/EXAMPLES.md withPageAuthRequired and getSession. Protecting a Server-Side and Client Renderer
